# Find papers that use specific sample groups

Tags: journals, code

I've been tasked with finding all papers within a journal whose sample groups contain children. There are journals between 1999 and 2023 that I need to search through.

My first thought was to try to create a list that could be updated as each paper is found that fulfills the sample group, but I'm getting a little overwhelmed on where to go from there.

Comment: If you have a list, then you have "found" them. What more are you asking for here?